# Python: Best Way to Measure Runtime Consistency for a Function?

Tags: python, time, runtime

I'm trying to test the runtime consistency for a function I wrote. I tried using time.process_time_ns(); however I get uneven results.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(100):
    start_time = time.process_time_ns()
    some_function()
    print("--- %s nanoseconds ---" % (time.process_time_ns() - start_time))
```

Here is how the results look:

```
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 15625000 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
--- 0 nanoseconds ---
```

As you can see, I'm mostly getting 0 nanoseconds, but then I get a random larger number, as if it's counting everything all at once.

I also tried time.perf_counter_ns(). The results with perf_counter_ns() made more sense, but I'd still get random spikes such as one you may notice in the results below:

```
--- 59100 nanoseconds ---
--- 59600 nanoseconds ---
--- 62900 nanoseconds ---
--- 59300 nanoseconds ---
--- 59500 nanoseconds ---
--- 58800 nanoseconds ---
--- 58800 nanoseconds ---
--- 59100 nanoseconds ---
--- 60100 nanoseconds ---
--- 338600 nanoseconds ---
--- 64400 nanoseconds ---
--- 67700 nanoseconds ---
--- 60100 nanoseconds ---
--- 60200 nanoseconds ---
--- 59300 nanoseconds ---
--- 59400 nanoseconds ---
--- 58600 nanoseconds ---
--- 58500 nanoseconds ---
--- 58400 nanoseconds ---
```

Why do I get these spikes using the time library and is there any way to improve this? Or is this simply inevitable due to background process / some other issues?